# Creating Func body dynamically

Tags: c#, reflection, dependency-injection, func

See the sample below:

```
var factoryType = typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(someType);

container.RegisterPerRequest(someType, null, someType);

Func<object> factoryDelegate = () => container.GetInstance(someType, null); //this returns an object, hence the delegate type is Func<object>, but the required type is Func<SomeClass>

container.RegisterInstance(factoryType, null, factoryDelegate); //Not sure how to create factory delegate
```

I would want to create the function body where an instance of `someType` will be created using a DI container.

The idea is to configure the DI container so that it can inject `Func<SomeClass>` into other classes.

How can this be done?

Comment: Well what would you call on the DI container to create the instance of `SomeClass`? Your question is unclear at the moment.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Please see the edit if it makes more sense.

Comment: `container.Resolve` returns object ? I think it should be generic and return a type.

Comment: Which container is this? It would really help if we knew the concrete details...

Comment: It is SimpleContainer, that ships with Caliburn.Micro. Here is the link https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=The%20Simple%20IoC%20Container

Comment: @VictorMukherjee Can't you cast that `(someType)container.GetInstance(typeof(someType), null)`;

Comment: someType is a type object, known at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Just cast the result:

```
Func<someType> factoryDelegate = () => container.GetInstance(typeof(someType), null) as someType;
```

Or create a method (Extension would be better):

```
static Func<T> ResolveTypeDelegate<T>() where T : class
{
    return () => ResolveType<T>();
}

static T ResolveType<T>() where T : class
{
    return container.GetInstance(typeof(someType), null) as T;
}
```

Usage:

```
Func<someType> factoryDelegate = ResolveTypeDelegate<someType>();
```